# React app deployed to IIS StaticFile handler problem

Tags: reactjs, iis, http-status-code-400

I have a sample React application. I deployed the application to IIS. Default page is OK, but /category page returns 404 - File or directory not found.

```
import { Route, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Home</h2>
  </div>
);

const Category = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Category</h2>
  </div>
);

export default function App() {
  return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Route path="/"><Home /></Route>
        <Route path="/category"><Category /></Route>
      </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Web.config file content. *runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests* solution not working unfortunately.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Detailed Error Information

- Module:      IIS Web Core
- Notification:    MapRequestHandler
- Handler:     StaticFile
- Error Code       0x80070002

ny suggestion please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using URL rewrite modul, redirect all requests to index.html file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
 <rewrite>
 <rules>
 <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url=".*" />
 <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
 <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
 </conditions>
 <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
 </rule>
 </rules>
 </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Is there an alternate way of doing this other than using the rewrite module?